# Postgresql: How to calculate an average of daily averages grouped by ID

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to calculate the average of daily average transactions grouped by month. 
I have the following transaction table:
**Transaction Table**
[image]

I would like to get the following result:
**Result table**
[image]

> **Average_Amount_Credited** = Sum of (Sum of Amount_Credited per month / number of days per month)/ number of months used
>
> **Average_Amount_Debited** = Sum of (Sum of Amount_Debited per month / number of days per month)/ number of months used

To come up with the result table I used 30 as the number of days per month.
I would like also to count the number of times per month where the `balance amount(Amount_Credited - Amount_Debited)` was positive or negative as shown on the result table.

The following is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
 "T"."ID", 
 date_trunc('month',"T"."Date_Transaction") AS "PERIOD",
 SUM(COALESCE("T"."Amount_Credited",0))/30 AS "Average Amount_Credited",
 SUM(COALESCE("T"."Amount_Debited",0))/30 AS "Average Amount_Debited",
 (CASE WHEN (SUM(COALESCE("T"."Amount_Credited",0))/30 - SUM(COALESCE("T"."Amount_Debited",0))/30) >0 
       THEN '1' 
       WHEN (SUM(COALESCE("T"."Amount_Credited",0))/30 - SUM(COALESCE("T"."Amount_Debited",0))/30) <0 
       THEN '0' 
 END) "Status Balance" 
FROM "Transaction" "T" 
WHERE "T"."ID" = '1' 
GROUP BY "T"."ID", date_trunc('month',"T"."Date_Transaction")
```

As you will see by my query It is returning one row per month yet I would like to return one row by ID which shows an average of different period averages.

Comment: What database are you using? This question is tagged with both postgres and mysql.

Comment: Can you show some queries you tried to write for this problem? We can help you with problems in your queries. We wont write queries for you.